# Generate PDF with Unicode characters in Android

Tags: android, unicode

Im trying to generate PDF file using android using following code.
This PDF file may contains both English and Chinese characters.
Chinese characters are not recognized as Chinese letters(Convert to images) but English letters are OK.

Any workaround for this issue ?

public void generatePDFDoc(Activity activity, View view, String pdfFileName) {

```
    {
        File pdfFile = null;
        PrintAttributes printAttrs = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
                setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR).
                setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_LETTER).
                setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("print", activity.PRINT_SERVICE,
                        25, 25)).
                setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).
                build();

        PdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(activity, printAttrs);
        View content = view;
        int width = content.getWidth();
        int height = content.getHeight();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(width, height, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        content.draw(page.getCanvas());
        document.finishPage(page);
        try {
            pdfFile = new File(pdfFileName);
            if (pdfFile != null) {
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
                document.writeTo(os);
                document.close();
                os.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error generating file", e);
        } finally {
            if (pdfFile != null) {
                //Success Generate PDF file

            }
        }


    }
}
```